# add javascript to elementor editor panel wp

Tags: wordpress, elementor

hi i'm working with `wordpress` and with `elementor` plugin, i made my custom widgets.. and everything.
but i need to have a javascript code `onclick` on a button in the editor panel a hidden input value changes..
i tried `wp_register_script` in `elementor` class 
but it seems it goes to the preview tab instead of the editor.. 
tried a lot of research on google but seem not much information about this.

i found this page 
https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/adding-javascript-to-elementor-widgets/

but i couldn't get it to work with me.

this is my class

```
    <?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if(defined('ELEMENTOR_VERSION')):

include_once 'manager/controls.php';

class reMAG_Elementor {

    public static $_instance;

    public function __construct(){
         if(!class_exists('ElementsKit')){
            add_action('elementor/controls/controls_registered', array( $this, 'control_image_choose' ), 13 );
        }

        add_action('elementor/init', array($this, 'remag_elementor_unit'));
        add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', array($this, 'remag_shortcode_elements'));   
    }


    public function reMAG_Elementor_unit(){

        \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->elements_manager->add_category(
            'remag-elements',
            [
                'title' =>esc_html__( 're:MAG', 're_MAG' ),
                'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
            ],
            1
        );

        add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', [ $this, 'widget_scripts' ] );
    }


    public function widget_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'widget-2', plugins_url( 'js/helper.js', __FILE__ ), [ 'jquery', 'some-library' ] );
    }

    public function control_image_choose( $controls_manager ) {
        require_once 'controls/choose.php';
        $controls_manager->register_control( 'imagechoose', new \Control_Image_Choose() );
    }

    public function remag_shortcode_elements($widgets_manager){

        require_once 'widgets/post-block.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Post_Block_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/post-slider.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Post_Slider_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/post-recent.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Post_Recent_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/social-media.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Social_Media_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/categories.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Categories_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/tags.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Tags_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/subscribe.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Subscribe_widget());

        require_once 'widgets/recent-comments.php';
        $widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Elementor\reMAG_Recent_Comments_widget());

    }

    public static function remag_get_instance() {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new reMAG_Elementor();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

}

$reMAG_Elementor = reMAG_Elementor::remag_get_instance();

endif;
```

any help or information would be pretty much welcomed